# How to ask for a contract with out a non compete agreement?

Tags: salary, negotiation, resignation, contracts

I got my first job offer, and in the offer it says:

> After joining service with us, you will undertake not to seek any employment with our competitors for a period of (2) two years from the date of termination, resignation or completion of your service without the prior approval of the company.

I would like to accept the offer but the salary is not enough even after  negotiating. Can I ask for a contract without a non compete  and will that solve the problem just in case I get a better offer? If so, how can I negotiate to have an unlimited contract and does this mean I can leave the company at any time?

Comment: Conditions like this are often not legally binding. You should check the legal situation in your country/state and just ignore any conditions which are not legal.

Comment: You write "the salary its not enough even after negotiating", does that mean all contract negotiations are done? You can always voice your concerns and wishes, just be prepared to walk away in case they don't (want to) change anything. What do you see as an unlimited contract? Usually you have a notice period, the length should be in the contract.

Comment: @Edgar This sounds like a non-compete clause to me. INAL but as far as I know those are legally binding and can cause a hefty fine if broken.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts: Are they legally binding all over the world? One problem with many questions here is that everybody seem to think everybody lives in the same country, "their" country...

Comment: @Edgar to be legal there has to be a consideration also any compete must not be overly broad ie if you worked for VW banning you from working from any car maker  would be to broad

Comment: which country is this

Comment: I know the linked question is a 1 year but the answers still apply just replace 1 year with 2 years where appropriate

Comment: @Edgar: If it's not legally binding, then why is it in the contract? It's in the contract, so you should assume they sue you if you ignore it, which costs money whether it is legally binding or not.

Comment: @gnasher729: Long time ago I read in a book about the law concerning a IT sales job I had at that time. According to the law it was possible to set certain conditions like no work in the same job for another company for i.e. 1 year. And at that time they also mentioned that it is not unusual that companies write i.e. 2 years or longer but this is legally not possible. I just describe what I read in that book which was written and published by reputable source.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/03/28/ndas-and-contracts-that-you-should-never-sign/ . . . Ask them whether they'll continue to pay your salary for the 24 months that you are not allowed to work in your field.

Comment: @Edgar: I don't care if its legal or not. You shouldn't accept things in your contract because you think they are illegal anyway, that's a bad strategy. You can tell them "I don't like this clause and I believe it's illegal anyway, so remove it".

Comment: @gnasher729: Sorry but if you don't care if a contract is legal or not you do something wrong. That's the last thing I have to say about this.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where you work but here, in France, it is mandatory for the company to compensate you in order to endorse this statement (25-50% of your gross annual salary). If the company don't pay, you are free to seek another job.

Search for your local laws and past court case to see if your local laws are the same.

Comment: I agree with you. But it seems this is a comment and not an answer to the question which was asked.

Comment: I can't comment anywhere for now, and I think we need more informations no provide a more complete answer.

Comment: I haven't heard of a legal requirement of this sort before, so I'm guessing it's specific to France.

Comment: @Dukeling: At least in Germany the situation is similar - but it may be specific to the EU.

Comment: In France, the clause should also be limited in time and space. For example, it is unreasonable to limit the employee from working for a competitor in a country his current company is not present.

Comment: @Adam Smith In addition, the compensation should be enought to not put you in a difficult position: 10% of annual gross salary is not enought to inforce a 2 year interdiction.

Answer (score 5):

Depending upon your jurisdiction and the details of the non-compete clause, it may or may not be enforceable. You'll need to consult a local attorney to get usable advice there.

You should also get clarification about what companies (or types of companies) are considered "competitors" to this organization. As well as *who* determines whether another company is a competitor or not. With a  broad enough definition and a jurisdiction that allows enforcement of such clauses, they could effectively prevent you from working in your chosen field *at all* for two years even if *they* fire *you*.

But, this may all be a moot point. If you're not satisfied with the salary even after negotiation, why worry about anything else? Just decline and move on.

Answer (score 1):

In the US they are generally considered non-enforceable except for very high-level jobs (think C-level or similar).

Keep in mind, if you are in sales, they may have recourse if you leave and take clients with you, especially if you have a non-compete.

Comment: I would be ***extremely*** careful about making statements like that, without legal advice

Comment: In the US, they *are* enforceable to a degree in most states. https://www.faircompetitionlaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Noncompetes-50-State-Survey-Chart-20170711.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The key part of your question seems to me to be "I would like to accept the offer but the salary is not enough even after negotiating."  The 2-year non-compete clause just makes the salary problem even worse.

Sometimes, your best option is to walk away.  This appears to be one of those times.